# I have started learning Scrapy and was trying to scrape LetterBoxd. I am unable to integrate Splash and Scrapy. How do I scrape the first 2000 pages?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
 
class Test4basicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test4Basic'
    allowed_domains = ['letterboxd.com']
    start_urls = ['https://letterboxd.com/films/popular/size/small/page/1/']
    # start_urls = ['https://letterboxd.com/film/tales-from-the-darkside-the-movie/']
 
    script1 = '''
    function main(splash, args)
        splash.private_mode_enabled = false
        url = args.url
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(0.5))
        return {
            html = splash:html()
        }
    end
    '''
 
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url='https://letterboxd.com/films/popular/size/small/page/1/', callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute", args={
            'lua_source': self.script1
        })
 
    def parse(self, response):
        for movie in response.xpath("//li[@class='listitem poster-container']"):
            movie_url = movie.xpath("(//a[@class='frame'])[1]/@href").get()
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=f'https://letterboxd.com{movie_url}',
                callback=self.parse_movie,
            )
 
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='next']/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url=f'https://letterboxd.com{next_page}',
                endpoint='execute',
                args={
                    'lua_source': self.script1
                },
                callback=self.parse
            )
 
    def parse_movie(self, response):
 
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath('//section[@id="featured-film-header"]/h1/text()').get(),
            'year': response.xpath('//small[@class="number"]/a/text()').get(),
            'duration': response.xpath('(//p[@class="text-link text-footer"]/text())[1]').get(),
            'genre': response.xpath('//div[@class="text-sluglist capitalize"]/p/a/text()').getall(),
            'rating': response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "tooltip display-rating")]/text()').get(),
            'language': response.xpath('((//span[contains(text(), "Language")]/parent::node()/following::node())/p/a/text())[1]').get()
        }
```

I am successfully able to **scrape** all fields apart from Ratings (which needs Javascript) if I **scrape** directly from any movie URL. I have tried to apply some logic for pagination as well but I get nothing when I try to crawl. Where am I going wrong with this code? Could it be prohibited by robots.txt file of Letterboxd, I don't see how.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Seems to me you need to make another splash request <a> link with class next to grab the next page. How do you think you could do this for all next pages ?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the question about the next pages. Sounds like a splash request for the next page link is required. You should have a think about how to continually ask for the next page link until there is none left.

To help you out slightly with the rating. It's not necessary to use splash to grab the rating.

If you look at the requests the browser makes when inspecting the page. You can see there's an AJAX request with some HTML corresponding to the rating, as you've suggested it's loaded by javascript.

[image]

I tend to copy this request and paste into curl.trillworks.com. Converting the cURL command to python. Then you can play around with the request to see if you can grab it without any headers etc...

[image]
Infact you don't even need headers/params/cookies to make the request. To get the rating information you make a simple HTTP get request to `https://letterboxd.com/csi/film/joker-2019/rating-histogram/`

### Code Example

```
start_url = ['https://letterboxd.com/csi/film/joker-2019/rating-histogram/']
def parse(self,response):
    rating = response.xpath('//a[@class="tooltip display-rating"]/text()').get()
```

### Output

```
3.8
```

For any film link you replace joker-2019 with the corresponding part of the URL that specifies the specific film page link.

### Update from comments

You've actually nearly got this. You've correctly made the code for the next page. I think your XPATH selector for each link was slightly wrong.

### Updated Code

```
for movie in response.xpath("//li[@class='listitem poster-container']"):
            movie_url = movie.xpath(".//a[@class='frame']/@href").get()
            print(movie_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=f'https://letterboxd.com{movie_url}',
                callback=self.parse_movie, dont_filter=True
            )
```

### Corrections

1. Note that it should be `.//` NOT `//`. `.//` searches the relative path of each `response.xpath("//li[@class='listitem poster-container']")` list item. Easy mistake we all missed this.
2. I'm not too sure about the XPATH selector

   `'(//a[@class='frame'])[1]/@href'`

   I've changed that to `'//a[@class='frame']/@href'` which works
3. It was filtering all the requests because it had the same BASE URL `letterboxd.com` so within the `scrapy.Request` you have to make sure the `dont_filter=True` to process all the requests.

### Update 2: Incorporating Rating into the code

See the main body of the answer but here is the implementation. We create the partial part of the link we need to feed to the histogram URL that gives us the rating. We then invoke a callback to grab that rating and then we transfer this variable in the rating method to the parse_movie method.

```
def parse(self, response):
        
    for movie in response.xpath("//li[@class='listitem poster-container']"):
        movie_url = movie.xpath(".//a[@class='frame']/@href").get()
        partial = movie_url.split('/')[-2]

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=f'https://letterboxd.com{movie_url}',
                callback=self.parse_movie, dont_filter=True
            )

        rating_url = f'https://letterboxd.com/csi/film/{partial}/rating-histogram/'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=rating_url,callback=self.rating)
        
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='next']/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url=f'https://letterboxd.com{next_page}',
                endpoint='execute',
                args={
                    'lua_source': self.script1
                },
                callback=self.parse
            )

def rating(self,response):
    self.rating = response.xpath('//a[@class="tooltip display-rating"]/text()').get()

def parse_movie(self, response):
 
    yield {
            'title': response.xpath('//section[@id="featured-film-header"]/h1/text()').get(),
            'year': response.xpath('//small[@class="number"]/a/text()').get(),
            'duration': response.xpath('(//p[@class="text-link text-footer"]/text())[1]').get(),
            'genre': response.xpath('//div[@class="text-sluglist capitalize"]/p/a/text()').getall(),
            'rating': self.rating,
            'language': response.xpath('((//span[contains(text(), "Language")]/parent::node()/following::node())/p/a/text())[1]').get()
        }
```

Comment: so I have updated the code where I have applied some logic for pagination and returning the HTML body from Splash but I still scrap nothing. I don't understand where am I going wrong here

Comment: See updated code. There was a couple of things you missed. Let me know if it works for you.